# How could I unlink a google plus sign-in on Android?

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I've been trying to do correctly Google Plus sign in and it's all correct except that.

Once I've done google plus sign in, I cannot try to log with another account. Is this right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply allow the user to select an alternative account you can call `PlusClient.clearDefaultAccount()`.  You probably also want to disconnect and reconnect the PlusClient to properly put the user into a signed out state in your app, as explained here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#sign_out_the_user

To actually disconnect the user from your app - ie. revoke permission for the app to call Google APIs on the users behalf, you need to call `mPlusClient.revokeAccessAndDisconnect()`, as in:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#revoking_access_tokens_and_disconnecting_the_app